How can I get the CPU & Memory usage from a service in Google Cloud Run using python?
I want to create a resource tracker for my pipelines (the majority are deployed in a Cloud Run Service). so that I can save a log every time they run with the CPU & Memory usage, something like this:
  "Resources Tracker": {
     "Memory Consumed (MB)": 15.01171875,
     "CPU Consumed (%)": 0.0
   }


I've tried to use psutil but it doesn't work when the pipeline is deployed (CPU tracks 0.0%).
I'm currently trying to use the Google Monitoring API to get this metrics, however, it has been complicated, this is what I have

from google.cloud import monitoring_v3
from google.cloud.monitoring_v3 import types
import datetime


client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()
project_name = client.common_project_path('tracker')

def cpu_allocation_time():
    metric_type = 'run.googleapis.com/container/cpu/allocated'
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    interval = types.TimeInterval({
        'end_time': {'seconds': int(now.timestamp())},
        'start_time': {'seconds': int((now - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)).timestamp())},
    })

    aggregation = types.Aggregation({
        'alignment_period': {'seconds': 60},  
        'per_series_aligner': monitoring_v3.Aggregation.Aligner.ALIGN_MEAN,
    })

    request = types.ListTimeSeriesRequest({
        'name': project_name,
        'filter': f'metric.type="{metric_type}"',
        'interval': interval,
        'view': monitoring_v3.ListTimeSeriesRequest.TimeSeriesView.FULL,
        'aggregation': aggregation,
    })

    response = client.list_time_series(request=request)
    for result in response:
        print(result)



I'm trying to guide myself using the following websites:
Monitoring-Api-Metrics
Monitoring-resources-cloud-run-revisions
Monitoring-rest-resources-timeseries


The Cloud Monitoring API is slightly gnarly and Google appears (!?) to be moving away from recommending using Cloud Monitoring (API) clients and using OpenTelemetry|Prometheus instead (see Create custom metrics). This approach does provide a more general-purpose solution. That said, you should be able to use Cloud Monitoring API directly (as you show). I'd encourage you to use the built-in metrics if you can

The metric_type in your code is incorrect. I think you want container/cpu/allocation_time. However, your approach may be incorrect. Your Cloud Run jobs will automatically report this metric to Cloud Monitoring service. You can then interact with the data through the Cloud Monitoring tools (e.g. Metrics Explorer).

Daz thanks for helping me, I’m gonna take a look at the Metrics Explorer and, Yeah you’re right, after posting the question I saw my metric_type was incorrect
